# Nodejs Multithreading: Only one of the thread receives the dbref.on('value', callback) event

Tags: node.js, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a multi-threaded expressjs server.

I have implemented firebase database and one of the way I use it is to handle a real-time player ranking (top 10 players):

- When the server starts, I setup a `dbref.on('value', callback)` where callback saves the current ranking to memory
- When a user submits a score, I check if that score belongs in the top 10, and if it does I update the ranking in memory `(Array.push > Array.sort > Array.slice)` and push the new ranking to firebase. If the score doesn't belong in the top 10, do nothing.

In theory, each thread would receive the new ranking when one of the other threads updates it. That's what it does client side without issue.

However, only one of the thread actually gets its `dbref.on('value', callback)` executed, breaking the ranking due to inconsistent data.

Why is it doing this?

How do I fix that?

**Here is how I setup the multithreading, using cluster:**

```
var cluster     = require('cluster');
cluster.setupMaster({
    exec:   path.normalize(__dirname+'/main.js') // Implements expressjs
});

// For each CPU core...
for (i=0;i<core_count;i++) {
    var worker  = cluster.fork();
    ...
}
```

**Here is how I setup and use firebase:**

```
var firebase    = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp({
    serviceAccount: path.normalize('firebase.json'),
    databaseURL:    'https://'+firebase_subdomain+'.firebaseio.com'
});

var localRanking = []; // The local in-memory copy of the ranking

var db  = firebase.database();

db.ref("path/to/my/ranking").on("value", function(data) {
    // This code block only gets executed on one of the thread, not the others.
    // If I have 8 threads, 7 threads won't get the update
    var value   = data.val();
    if (value) {
        localRanking = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've filed a bug internally, we're looking into this!

Comment: Can you share a full code snippet?  It's not clear to me where your firebase initialization code is running.  It'll need to be run in each worker process, not in the master.